# How to change desktop wallpaper from terminal?

Tags: xmonad, wallpaper

I want to change the wallpaper of xmonad from the command line.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [feh](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/feh):

```
feh --bg-scale /path/to/wallpaper
```

You can also set up bash scripts to change wallpaper to random one every X minutes(I use it with `feh`), get random wallpaper on each boot, etc. The Arch wiki explains it nicely.

Comment: I did it, but it isn't saved. When I reboot, the wallpaper is previous one.

Comment: @user53216
That's right. You've got to do this every time, or add it to some init file(either xmonad init file[I don't know xmonad, so I don't know where it is]), or put it in .xinitrc. The second solution is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://superuser.com/q/65953/151431) Super User Q&A, you can try:

```
xloadimage -onroot -fullscreen /path/to/background_image
```

Or

```
xpmroot /path/to/background_image
```

Or, and this should work on pretty much any desktop environment:

```
feh --bg-fill /path/to/background_image
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [xsetroot](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xsetroot) for simple backgrounds.

For a solid color:

```
xsetroot -solid black
```

For a bitmap:

```
xsetroot -bitmap filename.bmp
```